Swap SOLANA RAYDIUM node.js
is there anyone have an example for swap token on raydium in NODE.JS not typescrypt please ?
Sincerely
const { Connection, TransactionInstruction, PublicKey, Transaction, Keypair } = require('@solana/web3.js');
const { LiquidityPoolKeys, Liquidity, TokenAmount, Token, Percent, TokenAccount } = require("@raydium-io/raydium-sdk");

const bs58  = require ("bs58");

const HTTP_URL = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com";
const connection = new Connection(HTTP_URL, 'processed');

const walletkey = "3onho4yEyCL8wh6000000000000000000000000000000000000ZY6KNyqy4kDHeDCwxk"
const wallet = Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.decode(walletkey));

